Create an infinite callback loop in Dash
I'm trying to create callback loop in dash. My idea was to have a button that reclicks on itself until we hit n_clicks = 10.
import time

import dash
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc

from dash import Dash, html, Input, Output

app = Dash(__name__,
           external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP])

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Button(children='Run Process', id='run-button', n_clicks=0),
    html.Div(id='output-container')
])

@app.callback(
    Output('run-button', 'n_clicks'),
    Output('output-container', 'children'),
    Input('run-button', 'n_clicks'),
)
def run_process(n_clicks):
    if n_clicks > 10:
        return dash.no_update

    print(n_clicks)
    time.sleep(1)
    return n_clicks + 1, n_clicks + 1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True, port=100)

However the print(n_clicks) prints 0 and then 2 (skipping 1?!) and then stops, should be going until 10.
Any idea how to fix and what is going on?

where is loop in code? What if you use  return n_clicks, n_clicks without +1 ?

how about timer dcc.Interval(..., interval=1 * 1000, max_intervals=10) ?  Interval | Dash for Python Documentation | Plotly

Maybe you should use timer for this
dcc.Interval(..., interval=1 * 1000, max_intervals=10, disabled=True)

and button should change disabled to False to start timers.
And it should have assigned callback which runs code.
Something like this:
import dash
from dash import dcc
#import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
from dash import Dash, html, Input, Output

app = Dash(__name__)#, external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP])

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Button(id='run-button', children='Run Process', n_clicks=0),
    dcc.Interval(id="interval-component", interval=1 * 1000, max_intervals=10, disabled=True),
    html.H1(id='label', children=''),    
])

@app.callback(
    Output("interval-component", "disabled"), 
    Input('run-button', 'n_clicks'),
)
def run_process(n_clicks):
    if n_clicks > 0:
        return False

    return True
    
@app.callback(
    Output('label', 'children'),
    Input('interval-component', 'n_intervals'),
)
def update_interval(n_intervals):
    return f'Intervals Passed: {n_intervals}'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True, port=8000)


Doc: Interval | Dash for Python Documentation | Plotly

The infinite loop comes from the dcc Interval. But if we have a long callback (try sleeping for 2 secs) then only the last 'Intervals passed {n}' gets displayed

if you have long running code then maybe you should run it in separate thread. Usually GUIs don't like long running code because it blocks its event loop and it can't run own code. So maybe you need totally different code.

Firstly, starting from Dash v1.19.0 the case of passing the same component+property pair as both an input and an output within the same callback is specifically treated as an exception to circular callbacks. You may get more details having a glance at the pull request #1525. So it breaks the loop, actually.
Secondly, using button's n_clicks for synchronisation doesn't seem to be a good idea. Button's clicks are handled client-side first. Each one increments n_clicks and thus issues a callback. Possibly, many of them. But the outputs are populated with the results of the last issued callback (not the last received). Until that moment each new click leads to a callback with client n_clicks value, dropping all the received info from the server. To illustrate:
import random

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div(id='output-container'),
    html.Button(id='clickme', children='Click me!', n_clicks=0)])

@app.callback(
    Output('output-container', 'children', allow_duplicate=True),
    Output('clickme', 'n_clicks', allow_duplicate=True),
    Input('clickme', 'n_clicks'),
    prevent_initial_call=True)
def click_me_click(clicks):
    time.sleep(random.randint(0, 1000) / 1000)  # Random delay within 1 sec    

    clicks += 1000
    print(clicks)
    return clicks, clicks

By rapidly clicking the button, you may get somewhat similar output in stdout:
Clicks: 1001
Clicks: 1003  <<< shown in the output container
Clicks: 1002
Clicks: 2004  <<< increment of the last issued callback
Clicks: 2006  <<< shown in the output container
Clicks: 2005  <<< dropped

Thirdly, I assume time.sleep(1) means to represent time-consuming calculation which you want to execute sequentially and avoid any race conditions.
The possible solution is to put once triggered component inside a container. And in your main-loop callback rewrite the contents of the container with a newly initialised trigger-component.
Trigger:
from dash import dcc

RUN_ONCE = 1

# Needs to be positive. 
# Zero value will lead to default 1000ms = 1sec delay of dcc.Interval
DELAY_MS = 1  # 1 ms, no delay

def trigger():
    return dcc.Interval(
        id="trigger",
        interval=DELAY_MS,
        max_intervals=RUN_ONCE)

Layout, store the call count separately:
app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Button(children='Run Process', id='run-button', n_clicks=0),
    html.Div(id='trigger-container', children=trigger()),
    dcc.Store(id='counter', data=0),
    html.Div(id='output-container')])

Loop-callback:
from dash import State
from dash.exceptions import PreventUpdate
import random

@app.callback(
    Output('output-container', 'children'),
    Output('trigger-container', 'children'),
    Output('counter', 'data'),
    Input('trigger', 'n_intervals'),
    State('counter', 'data'))
def run_process(intervals_passed, count):

    if not intervals_passed:
        # Skip the initial callback after the layout is ready
        raise PreventUpdate

    if count >= 10:
        raise PreventUpdate

    time.sleep(random.randint(0, 1000) / 1000)

    count += 1

    message = f"Call count: {count}"

    print(message)

    return (
        message,
        trigger(),
        count
    )

